# Getting a big difference between training and testing prediction accuracy when dataset tested on SVM

Tags: regression

I used SVM for prediction purpose but I got a big difference between training and testing prediction accuracy when dataset. Can anyone guide me that what should I do to solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Having a big difference between the training and testing datasets can be accredited to "overfitting" and you should read on "The Bias-Variance tradeoff".

In your case you probably have high variance, which means that your model is very close to the true functional form of your sample but not of the population. In other words, your model is not generic enough to predict well on out-of-sample data.

What you should do is, trying to simplify your model a little bit and see if that improves the out-of-sample prediction.

Remember, overly complicated models might lead to overfitting.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, Kiril, as u suggested to simplify the model, so can you further pls suggest me how can I simplify my model? And, how can I reduce "The Bias-Variance tradeoff" ? Please suggest or provide me a link as I am a novice in data analytics.